# List split and join

Tags: python, list

Below is my list

```
MY_TXT= [
    'User enters validusername "MAXI" And password "768"', 
    'User enters phonenumber "76567898" And ZIPcode "97656"', 
    'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" And City "LONDON"  And  street "Brick Lane And avenue  "2A"',
    'User clicks ok']
```

I want split the list from 'And' and  join with base name , my list to be looks like this:

```
New_list= [
    'User enters validusername "MAXI"',
    'User enter password "768"',    
    'User enters phonenumber "76567898"',
    'User enters ZIPcode "97656"', 
    'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND",
    'User Verifys City "LONDON"',
    'User Verifys street "Brick Lane"',
    'User Verifys  avenue  "2A"',
    'User clicks ok']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a nested list comprehension you can get what you're after:

```
In [6]: ['User verifys '+j if 'User'!=j[:4] else j for i in MY_TXT for j in i.split('And ')]
Out[6]: 
['User enters validusername "MAXI" ',
 'User verifys password "768"',
 'User enters phonenumber "76567898" ',
 'User verifys ZIPcode "97656"',
 'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" ',
 'User verifys City "LONDON" ',
 'User verifys street "Brick Lane ',
 'User verifys avenue "2A"',
 'User clicks ok']
```

------- EDIT --------

I see that it's not always 'verify'. In this case you'll need to track the variable which is the one you want to use at the start of the string ('verifys', 'enter', etc)

```
In [17]: myList = []

In [18]: for i in MY_TXT:
    ...:     for j in i.split('And '):
    ...:         if 'User' in j:
    ...:             entryStr = j.split()[1] #extract the action of the user - enters, verifys, etc
    ...:             myList.append(j)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             myList.append('User {:s} {:s}'.format(entryStr,j))
    ...: 
In [19]: myList
Out[19]: 
['User enters validusername "MAXI" ',
 'User enters password "768"',
 'User enters phonenumber "76567898" ',
 'User enters ZIPcode "97656"',
 'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" ',
 'User Verifys City "LONDON" ',
 'User Verifys street "Brick Lane ',
 'User Verifys avenue "2A"',
 'User clicks ok']
```

Comment: mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem so people in the future can find it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list `new_list`. Using a for loop, split each string using `MY_TXT[i].split("And")`. Then `new_list = new_list + results`